# Associate a cookie with a page request in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I have a Web Application in which I authorize using ACS. I want to execute a specific page using Fiddler, however I need the "FedAuth1" cookie set so the page doesn't get bounced back to authentication.

Example:
Cookie: FedAuth1 = xyz

Url to execute:
    https://www.someapp.com/myapplication/order/list/

Result (because of lack of cookie):
    https://www.someapp.com/myapplication/Authentication/SignIn

Can/How do I set this cookie in Fiddler before executing the request?

Answer (score 5):

Your example looks exactly right, you can use the `Cookie:` HTTP header when making your request. So your Fiddler request window would look like this:

[image: Fiddler request]

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to test the API/url which have authentication enabled ,please try following , i am showing for MVC web API on IIS server. usually there are more than 1 cookie responsible for authorization ,so you may need to send more than 1 cookie in header as follows :
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:51000
content-Type: application/json
Cookie : .ASPXAUTH=xxxxx;ASP.NET_SessionId=yyyy;__RequestVerificationToken=zzzz